# Modx changing user group

Tags: modx

i want to change usergroup for user who has paid for subscription. I wrote that code

```
    $user = $modx->getObject('modUser', array('username' => $username));
    if( $user ){
        $user->save();
        $user->joinGroup('5');

}
```

but it`s still not changing his usergroup, what can be wrong ? 
Thanks for answer !

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to save user AFTER changing his group. Just try

```
$user = $modx->getObject('modUser', array('username' => $username));
if( $user ){
    $user->joinGroup('5');
    $user->save();
}
```